# Regex to get everything but last word in sentence of words seperated by “/“?

Tags: regex

What would be the appropriate regex to get everything of a sentence except the final word:

For example:

```
/hello/world     -> /hello/
/one/two/three   -> /one/two/
/foo/bar/ice/tea -> /foo/bar/ice/
```

Comment: What are the red highlights for? imo, you really could've thrown this together with your other question regarding finding the last word.

Comment: @Sephallia That's the SO syntax highlighter engine at work, you can't really control it.

Comment: @Sephallia Don’t really know why the red-highlights appear, something strange with the syntax highlighter...

Comment: Those aren't "words" and "sentences". Those are paths.

Comment: @Larry Seeing the regex answers, I'd just do this in the hosting programming language by scanning backwards for the first slash and using the index to get a substring.

Comment: What should the result be if the input is `/one/two/three/` (note the extra slash in the input)?

Comment: @MarkByers It should be “three” (i.e. the final / should be ignored)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regular expression     `^/.+/`

Comment: This seems to now work for the case of “/foo”, which I would like to return just “foo”. Could you please revise, thnx!

Comment: i seemed that need all without last, new regex `^/.+?/`

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+)\b\w+$
```

This is fine for all sentences.  No matter whether it has / or not.

Comment: I like that, but am curious how to make it repeating.  So given a paragraph, how to find all but the last words of each sentence? That's the problem I'm grep'ing the net for.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will help you

```
.*[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: This will just match the whole string. Or any string that ends with at least one ASCII character.

Comment: Hey, this regex match all examples of question and response to question: "What would be the appropriate regex to get everything of a sentence except the final word". be sure before comment.

Comment: So how does your regex handle the "except" part if it matches the whole URL?

Answer (score 0):

With capturing groups:

```
^((/[^/]+)*)/[^/]*$
```

edit:

```
^(/.*/)[^/]*$
```

both also work with non greedy engines

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*` to match any characters, then match a slash:

```
#^.*/#
```

Note that if you use `/` to delimit the regular expression then you will need to escape the `/` with a backslash.

```
/^.*\//
```